# CSS media queries and screen resolution

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to get these columns to show vaguely under these conditions:

1. When on a phone -- show one column (at 100%)
2. When on a tablet -- show two columns (at 50%)
3. When on a desktop -- show as many as will fit

Here is my CSS code thus far but it's not working as expected:

EDIT: I modified the media queries a bit and the background color is changing as expected...but the widths are not. To re-iterate...on small devices I want DIV's to take up 100% screen width...on tablets I want them to split the screen in half...and on desktop screens I want them to spread across the entire width of screen accordingly.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) { /* 568px or less */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 100%;
      -webkit-columns: 100%;
      columns: 100%;
      background-color: red;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 35.5em) and (max-width: 48em) { /* 568px - 768px */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 50%;
      -webkit-columns: 50%;
      columns: 50%;
      background-color: orange;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 48em) { /* 1024px */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 350px;
      -webkit-columns: 350px;
      columns: 350px;
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What styling kicks in for screens between 48 and 64em in width? Also, if you're using ems for measurement, why not use them for the column width, too?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle please

Comment: First thing: confirm that you have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` tag.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what the "not working as expected" means!

Comment: Why is the orange or second media query not forcing the width of each to 50%? EM's cannot be used because of the requirements I outlined in the initial question -- as I understand it anyway -- how do I use em's to fill up all space or split it in half?

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think u can use percentages this way, try typing `1` instead of `100%` which equals to 1 column and `2` instead of `50%` which equals to 2 columns

```
@media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) { /* 568px or less */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 1;
      -webkit-columns: 1;
      columns: 1;
      background-color: red;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 35.5em) and (max-width: 48em) { /* 568px - 768px */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 2;
      -webkit-columns: 2;
      columns: 2;
      background-color: orange;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 48em){ /* 1024px */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 350px auto;
      -webkit-columns: 350px auto;
      columns: 350px auto;
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wprdhswr/1/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your `columns` are working exactly as expected. Check out the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-number-and-width-of-columns

The issue is that `column-width` is the **minimum** width. If you set your columns to be `50%` the column will always default to `100%` because no matter what, the column will always be at least half of it's container (I probably explained that weird). You basically need to set a desired em or px size for your tablet view. Or, as Adriano66 pointed out, set the number of columns, and not a width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 35.5em) { /* 568px or less */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 100%;
      -webkit-columns: 100%;
      columns: 100%;
      background-color: red;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 35.5em) and (max-width: 48em) { /* 568px - 768px */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 2;
      -webkit-columns:2;
      columns: 2;
      background-color: orange;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 48em) { /* 1024px */
    div.listing {
      -moz-columns: 350px;
      -webkit-columns: 350px;
      columns: 350px;
      background-color: green;
    }
  }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/a65pb9re/1/